# Rellenar un input con un valor seleccionado en una búsqueda autocomplete. AJAX, MySql, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

esto componiendo un search input instantaneo y mi código es este:

El formulario

```
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" id="dscto" method="POST">  
    <input name="marca_cercador_nom" id="busqueda" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
    <div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
    </form>
```

la pagina que carga el formulario

```
             $(document).ready(function()         {$("#resultadoBusqueda").html('');});                 
             function buscar() {
                 var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();
                  if (textoBusqueda != "") {
                     $.post("search.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
                         $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
                      }); 
                  } else { 
                     $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('');
                     };
             };
```

Me envía datos a search.php y me lista las coincidencias. Todo correcto.
Pero al seleccionar una de las opciones listadas (desde search.php):

```
  <a data="$data" id="$id">$data</a>
```

Necesito que dicha opción aparezca seleccionada dentro de mi input, pero no puedo. He probado con:

```
   $('#busqueda').val($('#'+id).attr('data'));
```

Pero sin éxito. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

- Tras obtener el resultado `HTML`, asignale a los `a` que en el evento `click` ejecuten una función (en mi ejemplo `setBusqueda`).
- En `search.php`, podrías simplificar los `a` a simplemente `<a id="$id">$data</a>`

Así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('');
  

  //-----------------------------------
  // CODIGO SOLO PARA LA DEMO
  $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('\
    <a id="1">Resultado A</a><br/>\
    <a id="2">Resultado B</a><br/>\
    <a id="3">Resultado C</a><br/>\
    <a id="4">Resultado D</a><br/>\
  ');
  $("#resultadoBusqueda").find('a').on('click', setBusqueda);
  //-----------------------------------
  
});

function setBusqueda() {
  var $a = $(this);
  $('#busqueda').val($a.text() + ' (' + $a.attr('id') + ')');

}

function buscar() {
  var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();
  if (textoBusqueda != "") {
    $.post("search.php", {
      valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda
    }, function (mensaje) {
      $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
      // Asignamos a todos los "a" que en el `click`
      // llamen a la funcion "setBusqueda"
      $("#resultadoBusqueda").find('a').on('click', setBusqueda);
    });
  } else {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('');
  }
}
```

```html
<form accept-charset="utf-8" id="dscto" method="POST">  
  <input name="marca_cercador_nom" id="busqueda" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
  <div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fabuloso. Funciona perfecto. Solamente he añadido una línea para que el resultado desaparezca una vez seleccionado un valor:

He añadido esto a la función setBusqueda  $('#resultadoBusqueda').fadeOut(500); 

muchísimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Solo una cuestión más: si en el archivo php quiero enviar un valor diferente al del nombre  <a data="$data" id="$id">$data</a> y recoger el $id en vez de $data, cómo resuelvo el find() que recupera el valor de los a actualmente?

Comment: Fantástico, muchísimas gracias!!!